# Word Frequency Counter in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to make a word frequency counter in XSLT. I want it to use stop words. I got started with [Michael Kay's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470192747). But I have trouble getting the stop words to work.

This code will work on any source XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
   version="2.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">   
    <xsl:variable name="stopwords" select="'a about an are as at be by for from how I in is it of on or that the this to was what when where who will with'"/>
     <wordcount>
        <xsl:for-each-group group-by="." select="
            for $w in //text()/tokenize(., '\W+')[not(.=$stopwords)] return $w">
            <word word="{current-grouping-key()}" frequency="{count(current-group())}"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
     </wordcount>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think the `not(.=$stopwords)` is where my problem is. But I'm not sure what to do about it.

Also I'll take hints on how to load the stop words from a external file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $stopwords variable is now a single string; you want it to be a sequence of strings.  You can do this in any of the following ways:

- Change its declaration to

  ```
  <xsl:variable name="stopwords" 
    select="('a', 'about', 'an', 'are', 'as', 'at', 
             'be', 'by', 'for', 'from', 'how', 
             'I', 'in', 'is', 'it', 
             'of', 'on', 'or', 
             'that', 'the', 'this', 'to', 
             'was', 'what', 'when', 'where', 
             'who', 'will', 'with')"/>
  ```
- Change its declaration to

  ```
  <xsl:variable name="stopwords" 
    select="tokenize('a about an are as at 
                      be by for from how I in is it 
                      of on or that the this to was 
                      what when where who will with',
                      '\s+')"/>
  ```
- Read it from an external XML document named (e.g.) stoplist.xml, of the form

  ```
  <stop-list>
    <p>This is a sample stop list [further description ...]</p>
    <w>a</w>
    <w>about</w>
    ...
  </stop-list>
  ```

  and then load it, e.g. with

  ```
  <xsl:variable name="stopwords"
    select="document('stopwords.xml')//w/string()"/>
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I had tokenized the list in prior version...I should have caught that. I'll try your stopwords.xml idea also.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the current word with the entire list of all stop words, instead you should check if the current word is contained in the list of stop words:

```
not(contains(concat($stopwords,' '),concat(.,' '))
```

The concatenation of a space is needed to avoid partial matches - e.g. prevent 'abo' to match 'about'.

Comment: Thank you. It was tokenizing the stop words. I'll try you stopwords.xml idea to.