# Key word count in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, word-count

I too and looking at a keyword type of counting mechanism like was posted here [Word Frequency Counter in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280028/word-frequency-counter-in-xslt):

My wrinkle is that my keywords may have multiple words, e.g.:

```
<xsl:variable name="stopwords" 
select="('audio codec', 'dual audio', 'audio switch' )"/>
```

I was playing with the code from the above question, and had something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
   version="2.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">   

<xsl:variable name="stopwords" 
  select="('audio codec', 'dual audio', 'audio switch' )"/>
     <wordcount>
        <xsl:for-each-group group-by="." select="
            for $w in //text()/tokenize(., '\W+')[not(.=$stopwords)] return $w">
            <word word="{current-grouping-key()}" frequency="{count(current-group())}"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
     </wordcount>
</xsl:template>
```

Certainly tokenizing with the '\W+' breaks this into words, but then that won't match my stopwords, as they are and can be multiple words.

Can anyone suggest an elegant way to do the word counting when the keywords may have multiple wrods?

Thanks for any help in this!

Russ

Comment: Having stop phrases is incongruent with counting words.  Are you going to start counting phrases instead of words?  Then consider "w1 w2 w3"  Would you want to count (w1, w2, w3) or (w1 w2, w2 w3) or (w1 w2 w3) or the union of all of those sets?

Comment: If you're still going to be counting words, not phrases, but want your stop phrases not to influence the counts, perhaps it would meet your requirements to remove the stop phrases prior to performing the count.

Comment: SOrry for being misleading. My stop words are actually phrases that i wanted to count the instances of. I could think of ways of looping through, checking for each phrase, but was hoping there was an analogous elegant way of counting phrase occurrences like this example does for single words.

Comment: kjhughes, your answer just got deleted. Did you or someone else do that?

Comment: Had to fix to handle multiple `keyphrases` within a text node.  Restored now.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Given this input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<a>
  <b>match: audio switch</b>
  <c>no match:</c>
  <d>no match: audiocodec</d>
  <e attr="no match: audio codec"/>
  No match:  Audio switch/dual AUDIO
  Match x2:  audio switch/dual audio/audio switch
  No match: <f>xxx audio</f><g>codec yyy</g>
</a>
```

**This XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:f="http://example.com/f"
                exclude-result-prefixes="f">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="keyphrases" 
                select="('audio codec', 'dual audio', 'audio switch' )"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="docText" select="string-join(//text(), '|')"/>
    <keyphrases>
      <xsl:for-each select="$keyphrases">
        <keyphrase phrase="{.}" count="{f:substr-count($docText, .)}"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </keyphrases>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="f:substr-count">
    <xsl:param name="s"/>
    <xsl:param name="substr"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="if ($s and $substr and contains($s, $substr))
                          then f:substr-count(substring-after($s, $substr), $substr)+1
                          else 0"/>
  </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Will produce this output XML that counts occurrences of your "stop" words (which I renamed to  `keyphrases`):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<keyphrases>
   <keyphrase phrase="audio codec" count="0"/>
   <keyphrase phrase="dual audio" count="1"/>
   <keyphrase phrase="audio switch" count="3"/>
</keyphrases>
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't this be simpler? For example:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="$stopwords">
        <word word="{.}" frequency="{count(tokenize($all-text, .)) - 1}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Demo:
 http://xsltransform.net/94hvTyW
http://xsltransform.net/94hvTyW/1

To prevent false positive matches, e.g. "dual audio" matching "individual audiograms", you could use:

```
tokenize($all-text, concat('\W', ., '\W'))
```

Unfortunately, the XPath regex has no anchor for a word boundary (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25464233/3016153), so it might be safer to prepend and append a space to the $all-text variable.

Comment: I like simpler, but [this](http://xsltransform.net/94hvTyW/2) counts `<f>xxx audio</f><g>codec yyy</g>` as matching "audio codec" where it probably should not.

Comment: @kjhughes Probably not, but this is easily fixed by using another separator character (instead of a space) in the initial string-join.